# How do I delete my cached email addresses when composing in Outlook 11 for OS X?

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook-2011

Outlook 11 is not respecting the Preferred business email for a contact and instead autofilling based on a personal address that I don't want to send to (but still want to keep with the contact).

Comment: Sorry for the obvious query, but did you restart the application? Reboot the machine?

Comment: Yes and yes, thanks but that's not it. It shows them incorrectly sorted in the "Contacts and Recent Addresses" pop-up.